# Сортировка столбцов матрицы по возрастанию их сумм отрицательных нечетных чисел по модулю

Tags: c++

Есть программа, работает с матрицами.
Задача: отсортировать столбцы матрицы по возрастанию их сумм отрицательных нечетных чисел по модулю.

То есть:
Исходный массив:

**-7** -8 4

3 **-5** 0

4 **-3** **-3**

Обработанный массив:

4 **-7** -8

0 3 **-5**

**-3** 4 **-3**

Смог реализовать только проверку на нечетность и отрицательность числа, подсчитать все отрицательные нечетные числа во всей матрице и написать их сумму по модулю.

Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать функцию void sortMatrix, не вкурю как грамотней это реализовать, по-моему нужен дополнительный массив.

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
float Scaner();

struct Matrix {
    int rows, columns;
    int **ptr;
};

void inputMatrixRandom(Matrix matrix);
void inputMatrixKeyboard(Matrix matrix);
void sortMatrix(Matrix matrix);
void outputMatrix(Matrix matrix);
void removeMasiv(Matrix matrix);
Matrix vidileniePamiati(int rows, int columns);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    char v;

    int rows, columns;

    cout << "\nВведите кол-во строк матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    rows = (int)Scaner();

    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    columns = (int)Scaner();

    Matrix t = vidileniePamiati(rows, columns);

    do {
        cout << "\nВыберите действие:" << endl;
        cout << " 1 - Заполнение матрицы рандомными числами" << endl;
        cout << " 2 - Заполнение матрицы с клавиатуры" << endl;
        cout << " 3 - Выполнение задания" << endl;
        cout << " 4 - Вывод матрицы на консоль" << endl;
        cout << " 0 - Выход" << endl;
        cout << "  > ";

        v = _getche();

        switch (v) {
        case '1':
            inputMatrixRandom(t);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "\nЗаполните массив:\n";
            inputMatrixKeyboard(t);
            break;
        case '3':
            sortMatrix(t);
            break;
        case '4':
            outputMatrix(t);
            break;
        case '0':
            removeMasiv(t);
            break;
        default:
            cout << " [ERROR] Вы ввели некорректное значение." << endl;
        } // закрывающая switch
    } while (v != '0');
    return 0;
}

void inputMatrixRandom(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++)
            matrix.ptr[i][j] = rand() % 100;
}

void inputMatrixKeyboard(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++)
            cin >> matrix.ptr[i][j];
    }
}

void outputMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    cout << "\n\nПостроенная матрица:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            cout << matrix.ptr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void sortMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    cout << "\n\nЗадание выполнено:" << endl;

    int sum = 0;
    float b;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            if (matrix.ptr[i][j] < 0 && matrix.ptr[i][j] & 1) {
                cout << " Требуемые числа присутствуют.";
                sum = sum + matrix.ptr[i][j];
            }
            else {
                cout << " Необходимых чисел нет.";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nСумма модулей всех нечетных отрицательных чисел массива:\n";
    cout << fabs(sum) << endl;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void removeMasiv(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++)
        delete[] matrix.ptr[i];
}

Matrix vidileniePamiati(int rows, int columns) {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = rows;
    matrix.columns = columns;
    matrix.ptr = new int*[matrix.rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++)
        matrix.ptr[i] = new int[matrix.columns];
    return matrix;
}

float Scaner() {
    bool good = true;
    float a;
    do {
        cin >> a;
        if (!(good = cin.good())) {
            good = false;
            cout << " [ERROR] Некорректное значение, повторите попытку:" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << " > ";
        }
        else
            good = true;
    } while (!good);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно думаете. Завести массив размера количества столбцов, в который записать суммы для каждого столбца. Дальше сортировать его. Когда меняешь местами элементы массива сумм, менять соответствующие столбцы исходного массива. Чтобы делать это эффективно, стоит хранить матрицу наборот, первый индекс указывает столбец, второй строку. Тогда можно делать менять местами указатели на строки, а не каждый элемент по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет!